# Get the current network standard like LTE or 3G

Tags: c#, mobile, network-programming

I want to retrieve the standard used from a NetworkInterface instance representing a mobile connection (for example LTE, 3G, G, H, E etc). How can I do that? The programs target platform is the "normal" Windows 8.1, not Windows Phone.

Thank you in advance,
Turakar

Comment: If you give downvote, could you please also provide information about why you think this question "doesn't show research effort; is unclear or not useful".

Answer (score 0):

If you have a open socket you can get the type subtype of the connection with:

```
NetworkInterfaceInfo netInterfaceInfo = socket.GetCurrentNetworkInterface();
var subType = netInterfaceInfo.InterfaceSubtype;
```

and then check the subtype against `NetworkInterfaceSubType` [enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.networkinterfacesubtype%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Is there also a way if you are not on Windows Phone but on a tablet which uses the "normal" Windows? AFAIK The NetworkInterfaceInfo class is only supported on Windows Phone.